# PinchGestureHandler not working on android

Tags: react-native

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,Image,Animated, Button} from 'react-native'
import {PinchGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
export default function pinchZoom(){
const scale=React.useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
const HandlePinch=new Animated.event(
  [{nativeEvent:{scale:scale}}]
  ,
  {
    useNativeDriver: false
  })
const anime=new Animated.ValueXY(0,0)
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={HandlePinch}>
         <Animated.Image source={{uri:'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z4ls0-ZGnU4/maxresdefault.jpg'}}
         style={{height:250,width:'100%',transform:[{scale:scale}]}}
         />
      </PinchGestureHandler>

      </View>
    )

}
```

i have an android device, and it is not working, dont know why please help!!!!!
beside this PanGestureHandler working perfectly

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 6):

Enclose the `<PinchGestureHandler>` with
`<GestureHandlerRootView>`

It should look like this:

```
<GestureHandlerRootView> 
 <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={HandlePinch}>
         <Animated.Image source={{uri:'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z4ls0-ZGnU4/maxresdefault.jpg'}}
         style={{height:250,width:'100%',transform:[{scale:scale}]}}
         />
      </PinchGestureHandler>
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

And don't forget to import it from react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to solve the problem thanks to you. I'll leave a vote and go!

Answer (score 0):

Add `minPointers={1}` and `maxPointers={1}` to `<PanGestureHandler />`:

```
<PanGestureHandler
minPointers={1}
maxPointers={1}
...
/>
```